# In PHPStorm is there a way to avoid indexing *.phar files?

Tags: php, phpstorm, webstorm

I know how to [exclude meta and log files from index inclusion](http://www.kevwebdev.com/blog/setting-up-a-symfony2-project-in-phpstorm.html#exclude-folders) but in my application's `composer.json` I have both [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/goutte) listed as dependencies. Goutte includes a [goutte.phar](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte/blob/75c9f23c4122caf4ea3e87a42a00b471366e707f/goutte.phar) which in turn contains the source code for Guzzle. So when I go to use autocompletion I get this:

[image: PHPStorm finds a PHP class twice because it indexes a *.phar file]

Is there anyway to exclude a *.phar file (or any specific PHP file for that matter) from the PHPStorm indices?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right click on that file and select mark as -> excluded?

Comment: FWIW, in PHPStorm 9, you just need to right click the phar, then select `Exclude phar from project`.

Comment: thumbs up for answering with a question :)

Comment: I would like to Exclude it for any project forever.. doesn't make sense and takes days for phpStorm to index my current project....

Comment: @dhazelett The option to exclude the phar from the project is grayed out for me. I even tried applying a more general exclusion in the "Directories" in the settings, but it seems like it doesn't work either. It takes a decade to index the project, it's currently stuck on "Indexing 'PHARS'" and more particularly - on phpstan...

Answer (score 15):

From the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/excluding-files-from-project.html#d255166e385) :

> In the Project tool window, select the required .phar archive and choose Exclude phar from project on the context menu of the selection.

Comment: Alright meeseeks, you did your job here, you can disappear now!*hint**hint* R&M fans

Answer (score 5):

otherwise you can add `*.phar` to Settings -> Editor -> File types -> Ignored files and folders

[image: Ignored files and folders]

or alternatively to Settings -> Directories -> Exclude files

[image: Directories]

Comment: The best answer so far